# Jetty Doesnt Seem to Load jars located in WEB-INF/lib folder of an application

Tags: jetty, deployment

First, apologies, but I am green when it comes to JAVA.

I have a Jetty instance that I am starting using start.jar and passing it a start.config file.  The config file properly references additional lib folders that have shared jars in them.  The instance starts and runs properly.

I then want to deploy an application via a war file that has been created.  The war file has a WEB-INF folder with /lib and /classes folders.  The /lib folder has a jar that contains the files needed to run the application.  The /classes folder is empty except for some properties that get read.

Everything seems to work except that Jetty wont start the application.  This seems to occure because it cannot find a class that is located in the app.jar file that is in the WEB-INF/lib folder.  It was my understanding that jars in the /lib folder would be read in auto-magically onto the classpath.

Please advise?

Answer (score 0):

Turns out Jetty was working as described but the classloader was not happy with some conflicting class defs.